# stop form action from navigating

Tags: django, reactjs, forms

Im creating a registration page using React,  currently i'm using

`<Form action="https://xxxxx.amazonaws.com/production/accounts/register/" method="post">`

This works, but it navigates/redirects me to the django page, is there a way to set it up without the navigation/redirect?

I tried using `<Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>`

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch('https://xxxxxx.com/production/accounts/register/', {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        email: this.state.email,
        password1: this.state.password1,
        password2: this.state.password2,
      })
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("success");

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I get status code 200, which is success, but when i check the django admin page, no new user is added. For some reason, "Form action ="xxxx" " works but onSubmit does not, it might be that mode: 'no-cors' is supposed to be same-origin, but I can't test that as im on a local branch.

Comment: If using the form action I suspect it isn't using anything from react, i.e. your state, but instead grabbing the fields from the form directly. Have you compared the network requests? What does the successful one look like when using the form action as compared to the failing one using a formatted fetch? Can you copy/paste the curls here in your question?

Comment: attached teh request body from network calls
https://imgur.com/a/bQWCfYl

Comment: Only difference I can spot is the `accept` header.